# xubuntu: shutdown from panel menu takes too long, but terminal commands work fast

Tags: command-line, xubuntu, shutdown, xfce

If I shut down or restart the system using the `Panel > Whisker Menu > Log out` menu, it takes very long (1-2 minutes) to shut down (boot speed is normal). During this 1-2 minutes, the desktop environment remains visible and interactable (although the Whisker Menu button becomes unresponsive). I can launch programs etc. Then spontaneously the black screen shows and shutdown after this point is quick.

On the contrary, issuing a `reboot` or `shutdown -h 0` command from the terminal has an immediate effect. I've tried setting the `DefaultTimeoutStopSec` option to `5s`, but to no avail. How can I track down the root of the problem?

System: Xubuntu 18.04 (5.4.0-124-generic)

DE: XFCE

Comment: I suggest you start a terminal window, do `tail -f /var/log/syslog`, and while the tail command is displaying new messages from system log, do a shutdown from the "whisker menu".

Comment: @FedKad here is the output: https://justpaste.it/37tcc I've hit the shutdown button exactly at 20:16:00 for reference.